# Can you test apps on iPhone without a premium dev account using beta version of Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7

We all know that Apple announced during the WWDC that with Xcode 7 anyone without a premium developer account can test their application on a real device. But the stable version of Xcode 7 is not yet released so if I download the current beta version, can I test my app on my iphone?

Comment: did you manage to test your app on your iphone? I am just starting with swift and i like to test on my iphone as well

Comment: @alex yes i was able to test on my iphone 6. Just download the latest xcode 7 beta

Comment: thank you. i am new with swift coming from android. I have connected my iphone 5s with the latest xcode, but  i don't see the iphone as device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

But you will have some capabilities disabled.

As for example: **the ability to create app groups**